# Sample size using population's summary stats

Tags: variance, statistical-power, survey-sampling

I have a computer that's running software that has a large number of critical paths, each of which takes a different amount of time to run. I don't know which specific paths are running at any point in time, and many of the same paths can be run concurrently. (For example, in the current minute there might be five processes from path A, 22 from path B, one from path C, and so on; in the next the mix may be completely different.) I can easily record the amount of time it takes for each of these paths to run even though I don't know which path each measure represents; obviously that means I also have the mean and variance of the population as well as a histogram.

I'm interested in recording call stacks of a representative sample from the population of what's running. It's very expensive to do this -- there's no way I can generate the call stack for every process in the entire population. Also, sampling can't be done with replacement: I can record a call stack for a particular process once, and no more. I'd like to make sure that stacks from each of the critical paths are generated, even though I don't know which ones are running *a priori*. The question is, how do I know how many samples to produce? I want to generate *just* enough samples to tell me something meaningful about what's running in the machine, but absolutely no more than that. Like I said, generating call stacks is expensive.

My gut tells me I can use the population's variance to estimate the minimum number of samples needed: more variance should imply a larger sample size, and since I know the distribution for the population (appears to be exponential), I should be able to use a method that can give me a significance level. I don't think I can use bootstrapping because I can't sample with replacement. In any case, I'm at a loss to figure out what method should be used. Can someone give me a hand?

---

**Edit:** I think I can be more precise in formulating my problem: I would like to sample such that the sample mean and variance for each critical path is representative of each critical paths' population, to within some significance level. I think this means that I need to sample to accommodate the path that runs least often in the system. Does this sound reasonable, and is this a power analysis?

Comment: The bootstrap samples with replacement from the sample and not the population.

Comment: What do you want to know that you didn't already know before taking the sample?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks -- I thought it was the population, not the sample. As for "what more to know", the interesting bits are the contents of the call stack (which isn't purely a call stack since it also includes the data on which the process is running.) The hope is to survey a) the paths being invoked and b) the data being processed within them